# Swift - “EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)” Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging

I have released my app few months ago and I have more than 2000 users registered. I have had no crashes expect for one user that is saying that the app is crashing all the time on his device (iPhone 6). He was so kind to send me the crash report but I cannot find the solution to his bug or reproduce the bug at all. I told him to try to reset his iPhone but this did not solve the issue the app still crashing.

How could I debug this crash log and see where the error is happening? (EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP))

the crash report says:

```
Date/Time:           2016-03-27 16:02:15.15 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-03-27 16:02:13.13 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   My App                              0x0011d140 0x1f000 + 1040704
1   My App                              0x0013e0d8 0x1f000 + 1175768
2   My App                              0x0013c208 0x1f000 + 1167880
3   UIKit                               0x2a6aa64e 0x2a622000 + 558670
4   UIKit                               0x2a8d3032 0x2a622000 + 2822194
5   UIKit                               0x2a8d6f0e 0x2a622000 + 2838286
6   UIKit                               0x2a8eac14 0x2a622000 + 2919444
7   UIKit                               0x2a8d43f6 0x2a622000 + 2827254
8   FrontBoardServices                  0x277afc74 0x2778b000 + 150644
9   FrontBoardServices                  0x277aff60 0x2778b000 + 151392
10  CoreFoundation                      0x26461256 0x263a9000 + 754262
11  CoreFoundation                      0x26460e46 0x263a9000 + 753222
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2645f1ae 0x263a9000 + 745902
13  CoreFoundation                      0x263b1bb8 0x263a9000 + 35768
14  CoreFoundation                      0x263b19ac 0x263a9000 + 35244
15  UIKit                               0x2a6a3a16 0x2a622000 + 530966
16  UIKit                               0x2a69dfb4 0x2a622000 + 507828
17  My App                              0x0013d8ec 0x1f000 + 1173740
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x26064872 0x26062000 + 10354
```

Comment: That crash report is useless until it's been symbolicated.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how can I symbolicate the crash report if it is not coming from my device ?

Comment: As long as you have the correct `.dsym` "files" you can always use [atos](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/atos.1.html).

Comment: I suggest bundling with fabric.io and using crashlytics to log your crashes. It symbolicates and gives you crash analytics to boot.

Comment: I have already fabric crashlitycs on my app but it shows 0 crash

Comment: Fabric says "missing DSYMs"